# What does config_enable_dataset_recording configuration parameter means?

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to implement dataset recording (color frames, depth frames) for Tango device.
There is a config_enable_dataset_recording configuration parameter boolean flag In Tango C api.

So the question is what does config_enable_dataset_recording means? 
(hopefully this flag may be helpful for my task)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently disabled from the API side, originally, the idea of dataset is to logging data on to a specific disk drive.